# Loading RecyclerView elements upon overscroll

Tags: android, infinite-scroll, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecyclerView inside a SwipeRefreshLayout, so that when refreshing the RecyclerView gets reset. However, once I reach the bottom of the RecyclerView or overscroll it I'd like to add more items to it.

My attempt so far:

I've subclassed the RecyclerView, to implement adding elements once the bottom is reached like this (inside the OnScrollListener):

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();
mVisible = manager.getChildCount();
mTotal = manager.getItemCount();
mPastVisible = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
if (!loading)
{
    if (manager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() ==
        manager.getItemCount() - 1)
        {
            loading = true;
            loadNext();
        }
}
```

`loadNext()` is an asynchronous request that sets the `loading`boolean to false upon completition and sets the adapter like this:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(items, ctx);
setAdapter(adapter);
scrollToPosition(mTotal - 1);
loading = false;
```

The items are loaded properly, but the `scrollToPosition(mTotal - 1);` makes the last item be the first on top, while the new ones are added on the bottom, also since the views coming in are animated, older views sometimes stay drawn in the background/foreground while the new ones slide over them. Is there any way to implement this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleCount = manager.getChildCount();
        int totalCount = manager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleCount = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading && totalCount > previousTotalCount){
            loading = false;
            previousTotalCount = totalCount;
        }

        if (!loading && totalCount - visibleCount <= firstVisibleCount + 5){
            loading = true;
            loadNext();
        }
    }
};
```

and you don't need to call `scrollToPosition()`

Comment: if I don't call scrollToPosition the view is instantly scrolled to the first element in the list, also why do you use previousTotalCount? it's set but never used except for that if statement

Comment: @tofiffe You should add your new data list to previous list. `previousTotalCount` means total number of data after last load. `previousTotalCount` and `loading` control whether need to call loadNext().

Comment: Wouldn't that crash the app? As far as I know I'd need to call notifydatasetchanged, however this causes the list to be scrolled to the top

Comment: @tofiffe You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`, but it won't be scrolled to the top. It works fine.

Comment: That's the problem, it is scrolled as soon as I call it

Comment: @tofiffe Did you call `your_previous_list.addAll(you_new_list)` ？or some method else?

Comment: yes, the items are added just fine, but the view is automatically set to the top